# Error when executing a FULL OUTER JOIN query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

Hello I am trying to execute a query in `mysql` but i am getting following error

query :-

```
 SELECT * FROM user_registration FULL OUTER JOIN user_details ON user_registration.email = user_details.gmail
```

error is :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN dreams ON user_registration.email = user_details.gmail LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: there is no `full outer join` in MySQL

Comment: so what should i use to fetch data from multiple tables

Comment: I doubt you need a `full outer join`.  An `inner join` or `left join` should be fine.

Comment: Hi. We can't read your mind. Read & act on [mcve]. But google your question before you consider posting one. [ask] PS "fetch data from multiple tables" doesn't mean anything either.

Comment: There is OUTER Join : here is link : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Answer (score 2):

As there is no `full outer join` in MySQL, you can use `left` and `right` `outer join`s with `union`:

```
select * from user_registration ur left join user_details ud on ur.email = ud.gmail
union
select * from user_registration ur right join user_details ud on ur.email = ud.gmail
```

Comment: I AM not agree @potashin, here is a FULL OUTER JOIN : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp